# Creating a custom aggregate function in C# using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

Consider the following class:

```
public class TaxType
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public decimal TotalTaxCollected {get;set;}
    public string DetailXml {get;set;}
}
```

I got the following LINQ query somewhere in the code:

```
GetTaxTypesFromTheDataSource()
.Where(/*blah blah blah*/)
.GroupBy(t => new { t.Id })
.Select(g => new TaxType
{
    TotalTaxCollected = g.Sum(n => n.TotalTaxCollected),
    DetailXml = g.Aggregate(SumOfInnerElementsOfXml).DetailXml
})
.ToList();
```

Where SumOfInnerElementsOfXml is declared as follows:

```
private TaxType SumOfInnerElementsOfXml(TaxType t1, TaxType t2)
{
    //(a) Deserialize the t1.DetailXml & t2.DetailXml into 2 different arrays.
    //(b) Aggregate both arrays based on their IDs.
    //(c) Serialize the result into an xml string.
    //(d) Instantiate a new TaxType and set its DetailXml to the generated xml string.
    //return (d)
}
```

The above solution works fine, however I'd like to create my own aggregate function so that I can use it as follows:

```
GetTaxTypesFromTheDataSource()
.Where(/*blah blah blah*/)
.GroupBy(t => new { t.Id })
.Select(g => new TaxType
{
    TotalTaxCollected = g.Sum(n => n.TotalTaxCollected),
    DetailXml = g.MyCustomAggregateFunction(n => n.DetailXml)
})
.ToList();
```

How's that possible? I've tried several extension methods but unfortunately none of them worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your initial solution seems pretty fine to me. However, if you don't like it...

To create a predefined function (not lambda), I'd recommend first to get rid of anonymous type in your query - change:

```
.GroupBy(t => new { t.Id })
```

to

```
.GroupBy(t => t.Id)
```

This is also generally better, as you get rid of one boxing/unboxing per TaxType and transform `IGrouping<{anonymous},TaxType>` into `IGrouping<int,TaxType>` (easier to understand the semantics if someone inspects the code later)

Then, you can declare the method as follows:

```
public static class Extensions {
    public static string MyCustomAggregateFunction(this IGrouping<int,TaxType> source, Func<TaxType,string> selector) {
        // blah-blah-blah
        //return something
    }
}
```

You can later make it generic if the need arises.

I'd also recommend getting rid of the dependency on IGrouping, as you later may need to apply that aggregation elsewhere:

```
TotalTaxCollected = g.Sum(n => n.TotalTaxCollected),
DetailXml = g.Select(n => n.DetailXml).AggregateTaxXML()
```

and

```
public static string AggregateTaxXML(this IEnumerable<string> source) {
    // blah-blah-blah
    //return something
}
```

Sources/further reading: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc981895.aspx)